# Understanding of Brownian Motion

Tags: functional-analysis, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

My background is functional analysis rather than probability, but I would like to understand what is a Brownian motion. Below I'm giving my current understanding, can anyone verify whether I'm correct. Thank you.

Canonical Brownian motion $\mathbf{B}$ is a space $C([0, \infty), \mathbb{R}^n)$ equipped with a certain probability measure. 
We can write it as $\mathbf{B}= (B_t)_{t \geq 0}$, where $B_t ( f ) = f(t)$, for all $f \in C([0, \infty), \mathbb{R}^n)$. 
Measure is given by 
$$P \big( \bigcap_{j=1}^{k} B_{t_j}^{-1}(F_j) \big) = \int_{F_1 \times \ldots \times F_k}  p(t_1, x, x_1) \ldots p(t_k - t_{k-1}, x_{k-1}, x_k) \mathrm{d}x_1\ldots \mathrm{d} x_k,$$
where $$ p(t,x,y) = (2\pi t)^{-\frac{n}{2}}\exp\big( - \frac{| x- y|^2}{2t}\big)$$ for $y \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and it is defined on a $\sigma-$field $\sigma( \{ B_t \colon t \geq 0\})$.
From this definition we can conclude that $B_t$ is a Gaussian process, that is, that for all $0 \leq t_1 \leq \ldots \leq t_k$ the random variable $(B_{t_1}, \ldots, B_{t_k}) \in \mathbb{R}^{nk}$ has a normal distribution. $B_t$ has independent increments, and $t \mapsto B_t(f) = f(t)$ is continuous and hence show that canonical Brownian motion has properties which define usual Brownian motion - as a Wiener process.

Comment: Sounds like you understand pretty well! Sometimes we specify that the initial point is $x=0$, and call the resulting measure the Wiener measure.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The realization of Brownian motion as the evaluation maps $(B_t)_{t \geq 0}$ on $C([0,\infty) \to \Bbb{R}^n)$ is certainly popular, and the development follows along the lines of what you wrote using Kolmogorov extension type arguments to create the Brownian process from the *finite dimensional distributions* (basically the formula you gave for $P(\cap_1^k B_{t_j}^{-1}(F_j))$ are the finite dimensional distributions).

As you are coming from a background in functional analysis, I think it is likely meaningful to point out here the semigroup associated with Brownian motion. You might have noticed that the density $p(t,x,y)$ you wrote for Brownian motion is also the fundamental solution to the heat equation on $\Bbb{R}^n$: $$\partial_t u(t,x) = \frac{1}{2} \Delta_x u(t,x)$$ where $\Delta_x$ is the Laplacian acting on the $x$ variable. In particular, for sufficiently regular $f$, you can solve 
$$
\begin{cases}
\partial_t u(t,x) = \frac{1}{2}\Delta_x u(t,x) & (t, x) \in [0,\infty) \times \Bbb{R}^n \\
u(0,x) = f(x) & x \in \Bbb{R}^n
\end{cases}
$$ 
by convolution
$$u(t,x) = \int_{\Bbb{R}^n} f(y) p(t,x,y) \, dy$$
Written in terms of semigroups, we have that $u(t,x) = e^{\frac{t}{2} \Delta_x}f (x)$ where $e^{\frac{t}{2} \Delta_x}$ is the heat semigroup.

At the same time, since $p(t,x,y)$ is the density of $B_t$ you have
$$
\Bbb{E}_x[f(B_t)] = \int_{\Bbb{R}^n} f(y) p(t,x,y) \,dy
$$
where $\Bbb{E}_x$ is the expected value where the process starts at the point $x$; $B_0 = x$. Putting these pieces together, you have that $$ \Bbb{E}_x[f(B_t)] = e^{\frac{1}{2}t \Delta_x} f(x)$$
For this reason, we say that that semigroup associated to Brownian motion is the heat semigroup and that the generator of Brownian motion is $\frac{1}{2} \Delta_x$. What is particularly nice from your standpoint is that you can now investigate many of the properties of Brownian motion from investigating the (densely defined, essentially self-adjoint) Laplacian. More generally, you can follow this paradigm to look at *Markov processes* and their associated *Markov semigroups*.